# Rails 4 - Using Transactions along with Begin rescue block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a piece of code which is used to do following things triggered from a controller call.I am using Rails Transaction along with begin/rescue end block to make the below series of code execution more robust.Its as shown below:

1. Save the object
2. save the associations and update the attribute value
3. send email
4. send text message
5. redirect

   ```
   ###in my controller 
    def verify   
       @request=Request.includes(:user).find(params[:id])
       @request.transaction do
         begin
           if @request.accepted?
              ##this method will call 3 more methods in the request model
              @request.send_email_and_sms
              flash[:success] = "Request is moved to another state"
           else
             flash[:error] = "Request was not accepted and couldn't be moved to another state"
           end        
         rescue
           flash[:alert] = "There was some internal error.Kindly debug"
         ensure
           @request.reload
           Rails.logger.info "================Making GO AHEAD TOKEN FALSE AND DEACTIVATE VENUE====================#{@request.attributes}==========="
           redirect_to request_hall_path(@request.user)
         end      
       end    
     end
   ```

   `

Is this the correct way to ensure that every piece of code will execute else it will jump on rescue with the flash.alert message.

Is there any other way that I am missing to make this code/logic more fool proof and robust?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably should not be sending email or text messages inside the transaction. Email and SMS delivery can and will fail intermittently, they shouldn't rollback database changes. You should instead use a job queue that will retry failed jobs.

Comment: Thanks @meagar, Assuming if i remove the email/sms sending and handle them async..is this code still robust or need modifications ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a transaction block here.  You will want to use a transaction when you have an 'all or none' requirement.  An example might be something like selling a product and creating an invoice; you wouldn't want to have the sequence fail in one of the steps and have an inconsistent database state (ie: not deduct from stock qty but add to sales).

Also, in your case as you know (from comments above) sending email and sms should be done via a job async so it doesn't block the current thread.

Anyway I would think something like this would be fine:

```
 def verify   
   @request = Request.includes(:user).find(params[:id])

   if @request && @request.accepted?
     ##this method will call 3 more methods in the request model
     @request.send_email_and_sms # send async
     flash[:success] = "Request is moved to another state"
   else
     flash[:error] = "Request was not accepted and couldn't be moved to another state"
   end

   redirect_to request_hall_path(@request.user)
end
```

if your #send_email_and_sms has any db writes then you can probably use a job hook (ex: a delayed_job callback) to do the write so you know for sure the job has been completed successfully.  So register a callback so that when the email and sms has been successfully sent you can do like `request.update(email_sent: true)`

Hope that helps :)